# Activity does not open on android 11 when app is fully closed

Tags: java, android

I can open an activity by firebase FCM, but this works only for android <= 10, for android 11 it doesn't work. My app is completely closed, I only have the FCM service from firebase to open something. I don't know if the problem is occurring in i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Would the permission to overwrite other apps solve it?

```
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);           

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){   
            
            for(String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()){                  

                acao = remoteMessage.getData().get(key);                    

            }


            switch (acao){

                case "screenStart":                        
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.putExtra("key", "start");
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                case "screenStop":    
                    Intent in = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("key", "stop");
                    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;    

                default:
                    Log.d("TAG", "default................");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on why this isn't allowed at all](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that documentation. I need to open the activity in order to run startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_STREAM);
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Show a notification with a `PendingIntent` that will launch `DisplayActivity` when the user taps the notification (or perhaps an action button in that notification).

Comment: So, as I understand it, you must always have user interaction in order to do a certain action? Are these changes from Android 11?

Comment: I also noticed that services are not running in the background. I'm not sure why, I'll have to do more research.